# Removing extra unwanted data from a footer

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a footer that is automatically created in csv files by a different program I use and then I need to loop through all the CSVs and alter it. An issue I have run into is that when I fill in blank cells in a csv files with "NA", the footer is also receiving them so at the end of the csv file it looks like this (very weird footer) and I need it without all the NAs being filled in:

```
    ##END##,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA
    ##COLOR####ENDCOLOR##,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA
    ##FORMULA####ENDFORMULA##,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA
    ##NOTES##Notes,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA
    ##ENDNOTES##,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA
```

and I need to KEEP the original footer so the comment parameter doesnt work. It needs to look like this

```
    ##END##
    ##COLOR####ENDCOLOR##
    ##FORMULA####ENDFORMULA##
    ##NOTES##
    ##ENDNOTES##
```

Is there a way to remove the excess NAs just from the footer or to stop the code from reaching the footer based on a special character like #? I've tried searching the web and have only found information on altering headers but nothing about footers. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

The code I have that fills in the blank cells is

```
`df1 = pd.read_csv(filename, dtype=dtypes, skiprows=1, encoding='ISO-8859-1', quotechar="'").fillna("NA")`
```

Comment: why don't you exclude the commented rows when filling in the blank values?  further, an MRE will help for someone to reproduce and provide an answer. here is a link  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: That is what I am trying to figure out how to do. If I use the comment parameter in the code, it removes the footer entirely if I pass in # which i dont want. I'm wanting to keep the footer except for the NAs

Comment: You can manually search from the bottom for the footer rows, collect the column 1 values, and delete them from the dataframe.  Then you can append the footer after you write the CSV.  Convenience methods like `read_csv` and `write_csv` are great if you fit their very limited parameters, but they can't anticipate weird situations.]

Comment: @Tim I wouldn't call the 50+ parameters of `read_csv` with several options each "*very limited*" :p